# CUDA Not Present in Google Colab

Tags: python, cuda, google-colaboratory, numba

After selecting the T4 GPU runtime in Google Colab, I tried running the following piece of code:

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
B = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(10, 10))
B_device = cuda.to_device(B)
```

But the line `B_device = cuda.to_device(B)` seems to trigger the following error:

```
ERROR:numba.cuda.cudadrv.driver:Call to cuMemAlloc results in UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CudaAPIError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-c23b10abb298> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 B = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(10, 10))
----> 2 B_device = cuda.to_device(B)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv/driver.py in _check_ctypes_error(self, fname, retcode)
    393             if retcode == enums.CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED:
    394                 self._detect_fork()
--> 395             raise CudaAPIError(retcode, msg)
    396 
    397     def _check_cuda_python_error(self, fname, returned):

CudaAPIError: [700] Call to cuMemAlloc results in UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR
```

This is very strange to me, as I would expect that there should be no errors for a simple operation like this. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I had to click "Restart runtime" and then "Restart and run all".